# Module ip_tables not found

Tags: debian, iptables, modprobe

since my last reboot i cannot use iptables anymore.

When i enter `iptables -S` i get

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:508 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found.
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

`ip6tables -S says`:

```
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:508 kmod_lookup_alias_from_builtin_file() could not open builtin file '/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/modules.builtin.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip6_tables not found.
ip6tables v1.4.21: can't initialize ip6tables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Yes, i rebooted multiple times and that didnt change anything.

Comment: Could you provide the output of `lsmod | grep ip`?

Comment: did you upgrade your kernel?

Comment: No, it was after a simple reboot

Comment: "lsmod | grep ip" doesnt show anything

Comment: `/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/modules.builtin.bin` was empty and i replaced it with a file from my debian virtual machine. Is that normal that this file is empty ?

Comment: @chicks no i didnt upgrade anything. I just rebooted.

Comment: A couple of modules seem to have gone. This is getting weird. Now my tun network adapter is gone.